# How to solve Cannot establish a connection to jdbc error while creating and connecting database?

Tags: java, jdbc, derby, netbeans-8

I have got some problem while connecting my database in Java Netbean
The following is what happened "Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby:mia using org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver (Database 'mia' not found.)"

My database name is : mia
Im using Netbeans Version 8.2
[image: Connection Wizard Picture]

Comment: The database does not exist. Make sure you are pointing to the right path for the database, or that it actually exisits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `;create=true` to your connection String at the end. But I never worked with embedded derby only h2 and sqlite. So can't say for sure.

Comment: Note that `create=true` creates a fresh new empty database in the specified location. If you are attempting to connect to an **existing** database, this is the wrong direction to go; you should instead correct your JDBC connection URL to specify the location of your existing database.

Comment: Could be, but I also would expect there to be a way to only create the DB if it does not exist. Since otherwise, it´s kinda annoying. You don´t wanna ship your program that depends on an embedded DB, just to then have it break when someone deletes the DB file.

Comment: You are correct: `create=true` has no effect if the DB already exists.

Comment: Thanks Bryan Pendleton,

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all friends contributed to my question. Special thanks to you Bryan Pendleton. I would like to share with you about this, yes I got answer to my question through your best contribution.
The answer is:

1. Firstly, you have to create Database through Xampp. You can [Download here](https://downloadsapachefriends.global.ssl.fastly.net/xampp-files/7.2.6/xampp-win32-7.2.6-0-VC15-installer.exe?from_af=true)
2. Now Connect your database with java.

   => Create New Project in Netbeans

   => Right click on java package file

   => Then 'New'

   => Then find 'Master/Detailed Sample Form.

   [Netbeans photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItxSl.png)
3. Run and Test your database
   [Database completed...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnEUN.png)

Thanks and welcome.